# FlatListFooter can't be displayed

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to  add footer to my flatList : 
i try this code :

```
 renderFooter = () => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              paddingVertical: 20,
              borderTopWidth: 1,
              borderColor: "#CED0CE"
                }}
                 >
            <Button> This is footer </Button> 
           </View>
        );
    }
        <FlatList
      data={menuData}
      renderItem={({item}) => <DrawerItem navigation={this.props.navigation} screenName={item.screenName} icon={item.icon} name={item.name} key={item.key}  />}
      ListFooterComponent ={this.renderFooter}
      />
```

But  no footer appears when running.

Any help please

Comment: Do you mean sticky footer?

Comment: yes i mean this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a footer that remains at the bottom of the screen "Above" the list, then you can just add a View after the FlatList.

```
<View>
  <FlatList style={{flex: 1}} />
  <View 
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      height: 50,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: thankx.  I wanna know how can i display  items fro  right to left ?

Comment: @SihemHcine add the following style attribute to the parent of the items you want displayed right to left: 

`style={{
  flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
}}`

Answer (score 1):

You used the component

> ListFooterComponent

in right way. you need to check your render method for footer. I faced the same issue and i follow [this](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6) example, and it helps me. I hope it will help you.

Comment: am following this doc.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way/hack. In the menuData array, you just add a flag (i called) to the child object to indicate that it's a last item. For eg:

If you can modify your menuData structure, added lastItem prop true to indicate that it's the last item :

```
const menuData = [
    {name:'menu1', screenName:'screen1', icon:'../assets/icon1.png'},   
    {name:'menu2', screenName:'screen2', icon:'../assets/icon2.png', lastItem:true}
];
```

and then

```
 renderFlatItems = ({item}) => {
     const itemView = null;
     if (!items.lastItem) {
        itemView = <DrawerItem navigation={this.props.navigation} screenName={item.screenName} icon={item.icon} name={item.name} key={item.key}  />
     } else {
        itemView = <View style={{padding:100}}><Button> This is footer </Button> </View>
     }  

     return {itemView};
 }
```

then use it in the Flatlist like so

```
 <FlatList
  data={menuData}
  renderItem={this.renderFlatItems}
  />
```